# Using $ sign vs @ sign to avoid string interruption

Tags: c#, string, syntax, syntax-error

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878549/whats-with-the-dollar-sign-string) doesn't explain exactly what the differences between theses two are, can somebody explain that more?

I've always known of using a `@` sign before a string when using slashes in the string to avoid interruption like:

```
Console.WritLine(@"string /");
```

Lately I've seen some people writing with `$` like:

```
Console.WritLine($"string /");
```

I've tried to see if that works, but it doesn't even work for me it gives me a runtime error.

Does anybody know if that is even a syntax in C#?

Comment: New C#6 feature called string interpolation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: They serve completely different purposes.  `$` is a compiler feature to shorten `ToString(pattern, values[])` calls.  It's not a replacement or alternative for `@`.  Look at the questions marked as duplicates in your two identical questions to understand the difference.

Comment: @DStanley thanks, my bad I didn't hear of it until now.