# Difference between $ and @ c#

Tags: c#, string, syntax, syntax-error

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878549/whats-with-the-dollar-sign-string) doesn't explain exactly what the differences between these two are, can somebody explain that more?

What is the difference between

```
Console.WritLine(@"string /");
```

and

```
Console.WritLine($"string /");
```

Comment: For `@`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c/556142#556142), for `$` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx)

Comment: Hmm... now not sure which question to close this as a duplicate of...

Comment: @JonSkeet I chose the `@` duplicate since the question already links to a `$` question.