# Is placeholders necessary on c# when printing variables

Tags: c#, c++, string, console-application

In C++ when you defined a variable and you want to print it you can just do

```
cout << "Your varibales is" << var1 << endl;
```

But why in c# you need a placeholder to do so?

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}" , answer);
```

Because i'm getting an error with printing the answer without the `placeholder`.
I have searched on the web, but it doesn't give the information i need..

Comment: As an alternative to the answers below, you could also choose to use [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) if you are using C# 6. It can make your strings more readable most of the time: `Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {answer}");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary you can do like this using concatenation subject to the condition that the variable must be a string , or else you have to use `.ToString()` for conversion and also to format the object:

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer); // if answer is string
```

let `answer` be a DateTime object and you want to print the date only from that with the format "dd-MMM-yyyy" then you can use like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")); // if answer is not string
```

Comment: you do not need to call `answer.ToString()` explicitly :)

Answer (score 2):

Because this is the way how `String.Format` works. `Console.WriteLine` uses `String.Format` internally. You could write something like `Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders are only used for *string formatting*: internally the `WriteLine` method will call the [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but you can either format it yourself, or use multiple `Console.Write` statements:

```
Console.Write("The answer is ");
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

For instance is more or less equivalent to what you do in you C++ program since the statement:

```
cout << "Your varibales is" << var1 << endl;
```

basically boils down to:

```
cout2 = cout << "Your varibales is";
cout3 = cout2 << var1;
cout3 << endl;
```

and `<<` on a `cout` is more or less equivalent to calling `Write` on the `Console`; the `<<` simply returns the console object such that one can use *chaining*.

Answer (score 1):

When you try

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer is " , answer); //without placeholder
```

This wont give you error but would not print the `answer` and the console output would be `The answer is` since you havent told where to put the variable `answer` in here. So if you want to print the answer you can use either concatenate using `+` as suggested by other post or you have to use placeholder

Letz take an example to understand where to use what. Let say you have many variables to show in the output. You can use placeholder so that it would be easy to read. Such as

```
string fname = "Mohit";
string lname = "Shrivastava";
string myAddr = "Some Place";
string Designation = "Some Desig";
```

Now letz say we wanted to show some string on the output which is like

> Hey!! `Mohit` whose last name would be `Shrivastava` is currently living at `Some Place` and he is working as `Some Desig` with so n so company.

Thus one of the way could be which is *suggested by many of us*.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hey!! " + fname + " whose last name would be " + lname + " is currently living at " + myAddr + " and he is working as " + Designation + " with so n so company.");
```

In this scenario Placeholder plays a vital role for better readability like

```
Console.WriteLine("Hey!! {0} whose last name would be {1} is currently living at {2} and he is working as {3} with so n so company.",fname,lname,myAddr,Designation);
```

With [C#6.0 String Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878668/3796048) you can also do it in efficient way like

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hey!! {fname} whose last name would be {lname} is currently living at {myAddr} and he is working as {Designation} with so n so company.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *string interpolation* in addition to these other answers:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {answer}");
```