# Exception is thrown when using {StringToReplace} and {0} in String.Format()

Tags: c#, asp.net

As Example,

```
string str= string.Format(@"<p style=""font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size: 12pt;"" >Total Qty {qty} on Date {0} </p>",dr["Date"]);
```

I want to replace qty later on.It throws exception `"Input string was not in a correct format"`.

Can anyone tell the reason and possible solution?

Comment: In short: The `{qty}` string representation doesn't have equivalent source to show up. "@" sign used for literal string, use "$" instead.

Comment: You already have a value on your {0} as specific date?

Comment: Do you want the formatted string to be
`"Total Qty {qty} on Date 01/01/2017"`
or
`"Total Qty 10 on Date 01/01/2017"`
if say the value of qty is 10
?

Comment: Correct solution is

    string str= string.Format(@"<p style=""font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size: 12pt;"" >Total Qty {{qty}} on Date {0} </p>","01/01/2017");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use like this :

```
string str= string.Format(@"Total Qty {{qty}} on Date {0}","01/01/2017");
```

to get the output as `Total Qty {qty} on Date 01/01/2017`. you have not give any notes on the `qty`, If it is a variable and you wanted to display its value in between `{` and `}` then you should use `$` instead for `@` and this time the code will be like this:

```
int qty = 10;
string str = string.Format($"Total Qty : {qty} on Date : {{0}}","01/01/2017");
```

This time you will get the output as `Total Qty : 10 on Date : 01/01/2017`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: it would be great

Comment: string str= string.Format(@"Total Qty {{qty}} on Date {0}","01/01/2017"); works!! thanks

Comment: @AmitBhatt: Glad to hear that It worked. happy codding. You can mark it as accepted if it completely solves your problem

Comment: how you replaced {qty} with 10 in string.Format($"Total Qty : {qty} on Date : {{0}}","01/01/2017");

Comment: Where `qty` is an integer  variable  initialized with `10` see the updates

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `$` instead of `@` because. In [String Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878668/3796048)
, we simply prefix the string with a $ (much like we use the @ for verbatim strings). Then, we simply surround the expressions we want to interpolate with curly braces (i.e. { and })

```
int qty = 10;
string str = string.Format($"Total Qty {qty} on Date {{0}}","01/01/2017");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The output is

> Total Qty 10 on Date 01/01/2017

The [Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VrGWDK) can be seen

Comment: This throw an error. Expression expected on $ and at the end of the code.

Comment: The fiddle says `Total Qty 10 on Date 0` then where is the supplied date `"01/01/2017"`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava : I don't have the privilege to remove other's votes. down voter will remove that for you, anyway the fiddle is still says `Total Qty 10 on Date 0`

Comment: @un-lucky Sorry I haven't updated the Fiddle path. Now its been updated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this format:

```
$"Total Qty {qty} on Date {{0}}","01/01/2017"
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJjJyS

Comment: assuming you dont want the formatted string to be `"Total Qty {qty} on Date 01/01/2017"` but want it as `"Total Qty 10 on Date 01/01/2017"` where qty has a value of 10.