# Clean way to concatenate a char and an int

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I have a coordinate class with two `int`s that has a method to show the coordinate as "A1" or "C5".

For the letter I'm using a char, and I don't know what's the best way to concatenate the two variables.

The return of the method looks like this:

```
//letter is a char
//line is an int
return letter+""+line;
```

I'm using `""` because it implicitly casts the char and the int as strings. If `letter` was a string I could just do `return letter+line;` but with a `char` the implicit conversion doesn't work.

I'm not really satisfied with this way, should I? What would be a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
return $"{letter}{line}";
```

Comment: Tthat's a great way to do it. It's a little low on explanations though, so I'm linking [this answer on the dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878549/whats-with-the-dollar-sign-string) which explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

This I guess is the best way to do it:

```
return String.Concat(letter, line);
```