# How to create an IIS website that runs a PowerShell function and shows its output?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, powershell

I've created a **PowerShell function** (called `Get-FileInUse`) that will parse our data server for a list of known files.
The function returns (`$global:result` as array) which files are in use and by whom.

I'd like to host an internal website that shows (when accessing it or when pressing a button on the site) the output of this function. Say an internal website `inusefiles.corp.com`. Don't bother about bindings and DNS records, I'll manage that.

I've followed a tutorial online ([this one](https://www.itdroplets.com/create-a-powershell-web-application/)), but it's hard to understand what's going on.

These are my two questions:

1. **How do I add my script in the aspx.cs file?** I would like to have the script run when loading the page. Placing it under `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` seems logical to me.
2. **My function returns a variable `$result`. How do I show it in eg. a text box?**

*Note: I don't have any experience with ASP.NET/Web Forms. PowerShell is no problem for me.*

Comment: This seems to be an exact copy of the question you posted yesterday and had closed due to it being too broad and that you then deleted. I noticed you commented on my answer that you were getting "compilation errors" but you never specified _which errors_.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I kind of had no other choice... Error was: `Compiler Error Message: CS1056: Unexpected character '$'`.

Comment: In `Line 14: ps.AddScript($". {scriptPath}").AddStatement().AddScript("Get-FileInUse").AddCommand("Out-String");`

Comment: what version of C# are you using? The $ sign isn't valid [until C# 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878549/whats-with-the-dollar-sign-string).

Comment: Sorry for the noobish question, but where can I check this?

Comment: Never mind, found it:
`Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3752.0` 

`for C# 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it:

Under `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` came:

```
string scriptOutput = "";
using (var ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create(System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()))
{
    ps.AddStatement().AddScript("Get-FileInUse").AddCommand("Out-String");

    foreach (var res in ps.Invoke())
    {
        scriptOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, scriptOutput, res);
    }
}
Result.Text = scriptOutput;
```

While my Default.aspx contains a ASP Textbox with ID="Result":

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Result" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="50%" Height="300" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```